# In hierarchical data, how to select all nodes up to the root level?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

If I have hierarchical data represented in a table like this:

```
team_id    team_name     parent_id
1          Sales         (null)
2          Executives    (null)
3          EMEA Sales    1
4          APAC Sales    1
5          UK Sales      3
```

Given one team_id, what would be the SQL to select all team_ids that lead to the root level? I'm using Oracle 11.2.

For example, given team_id 5, the team_ids returned should be: (5,3,1)
Or, given team_id 4, then the output should be: (4,1)

It's reasonably trivial to traverse down tree branches, showing the data hierarchy, using something like:

```
    SELECT team_id, team_name, parent_id
      FROM teams
START WITH team_name = 'Sales'
CONNECT BY PRIOR team_id = parent_id
;
```

I am looking for the opposite - traversing up a tree branch from a particular node.

Note that the sample data here is only 3 levels, but I'm looking for a solution for an arbitrary number of levels.

Comment: read up on CONNECT BY  .  Please show sample expected output.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Indeed I'm familiar with CONNECT BY. It's reasonably trivial to traverse _down_ the tree's branches from the root node, but I want to traverse _up_ the tree, up just one branch

Comment: CONNECT BY PRIOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH test AS
  ( SELECT 1 team_id, 'Sales team_name', NULL parent_id FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2, 'Executives' , NULL FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3, 'EMEA Sales', 1 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4, 'APAC Sales', 1 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 5, 'UK Sales' , 3 FROM dual
  )
SELECT team_id
FROM test
  START WITH team_id         = 5
  CONNECT BY prior parent_id = team_id
```

Comment: Of course. PRIOR refers to the parent row - but "parent" is an arbitrary concept that depends on how you visualise the tree. By using the PRIOR operator on the parent_id field, the hierarchy is "reversed" and it then becomes trivial to traverse "upwards". Thanks